# IMG path to db and then show it

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload image path to DB in a table with next structure:

[image]

This is HTML (I did not include other form-groups, only image one.):

```
<?php 

include "src/post/Image.php";

$connection = new Db();
$conn = $connection->connect();

$image = new Image();
$img = "";

$query = "SELECT * FROM category";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if(isset($_POST['publish'])){

    $img = $image->insertimg();

}

?>


<form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-group">

    <label for="image">
        File input
    </label>

    <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control-file" id="image" required>

</div>

<button type="submit" name="publish" class="btn btn-dark">
    Publish
</button>

</form>


<?php

$data = "SELECT * from post" or die(mysqli_error());

$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $data);

while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><img src='images/$info[0].jpg'></td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";

}

?>
```

And this is a class:

```
<?php

include "src/db/Db.php";


class Image{

public $target = "images/";
public $title;
public $category;
public $description;
public $text;
public $pic;

public function insertimg(){

    $connection = new Db();
    $conn = $connection->connect();

    $this->target = $this->target . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

    $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO post(title, category, description, text, image) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $query->bind_param('sssss', $this->title, $this->category, $this->description, $this->text, $this->pic);

    $this->title = $_POST['title'];
    $this->category = $_POST['selectcategory'];
    $this->description = $_POST['description'];
    $this->text = $_POST['text'];
    $this->pic = ($_FILES['image']['name']);

    $query->execute();

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $this->target)){

        echo "<script> alert('Image inserted into database.') </script>";

    } else{

        echo "<script> alert('Error.') </script>";

    }

}

}


?>
```

Last, this is my 'file structure' (I post this because think I made some kind of "path" error):

[image]

An error:

[image]

When I click `publish` it shows an error alert.

Then >
34 is `if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $this->target))`

On the page where I'm trying to show it:

[image] depends of the size.

**EDIT**

This is what I did in `<img>` :

```
echo "<td><img src='src/post/images/" .$info[0].".png' /></td>";
```

Hardcoded `.png` because my image file has that extension.

So when I open an image on a new page path is `marenews/src/post/images/14.png`

and in that way its working.

How to get rid of that?

**LAST EDIT:**

I did it. (var_dump saved me)

```
 echo "<td><img src='src/post/images/" .$info[5]."' /></td>";
```

[5] or #6 in the DB table is an image path. Now i don't need a hardcoded extension.

Comment: Your target location is likely not what you believe it is or want it to be. Try using the full absolute path to where the images directory is in your `$target` variable in your class.

Comment: @Dave Yea, I knew it was obvious. With the absolute path image was successfully added to DB. 
But still got a problem with the last thing in my post, image not showing :(

Comment: Look at the generated source and make sure the `src` tag is correct.

Comment: @Dave Can't figure it out. Is anyone willing to help?

Comment: `echo "<td><img src='src/post/images/" .$info[0]."' /></td>";`
This is my current `<img>` **When i open on new page that strange img icon, PATH is good!**

Comment: What does `$info[0]` contain?

Comment: @Dave Okey, I have done it with some hardcoding.. But i dont like it!! Ill edit my post right now  that you can see.